# Plotting a spline function with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to plot a spline function with ggplot2. When I use this:

```
library(ggplot2)

spline_x <- 1:6
spline_y <- c(0, 0.5, 2, 2, 0.5, 0)
spl_fun <- splinefun(spline_x, spline_y)

p <- ggplot()
p + stat_function(fun = spl_fun) + xlim(min(spline_x), max(spline_x)) + ylim(min(spline_y), max(spline_y))
```

I get an empty plot. The same thing with plot() works:

```
plot(spl_fun,
     xlim = c(min(spline_x), max(spline_x)),
     ylim = c(min(spline_y) - 1, max(spline_y) + 1)
    )
```

As an aside, how do I split the line with `stat_function` over multiple lines? If I just enter newlines (like in the `plot()` example), it (of course) stops evaluating after the call to `stat_function` and doesn't consider the x/ylim any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't given `ggplot` anything to work with and no values to pass to the function. Try:

```
library(ggplot2)

spline_x <- 1:6
spline_y <- c(0, 0.5, 2, 2, 0.5, 0)
spl_fun <- splinefun(spline_x, spline_y)

p <- ggplot(data.frame(x=spline_x, y=spline_y), aes(x, y))
p <- p + stat_function(fun = spl_fun)
p
```

[image]

```
p <- p + xlim(min(spline_x), max(spline_x))
p <- p + ylim(min(spline_y), max(spline_y))
p
```

[image]

In the soon-to-be-released new ggplot2 (install via devtools) you can use `geom_xspline` in my (also, soon-to-be-released) `ggalt` package which has a `geom_xspline` function (which will produce similar results depending on the parameters):

```
library(ggplot2) # devtools::install_github("hadley/ggplot2")
library(ggalt)   # devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/ggplot2")

spline_x <- 1:6
spline_y <- c(0, 0.5, 2, 2, 0.5, 0)

p <- ggplot(data.frame(x=spline_x, y=spline_y), aes(x, y))
p <- p + geom_xspline(spline_shape=1)
p
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It seems that I was (probably 'am') having misconceptions about how things fit together in ggplot2. As a followup question (I can post as a new question if you prefer), how would I now go about drawing the first derivative of this function on top of it? For starters I can't get deriv() to work on a function object, and secondly - if the original plot p was created with spline_x and spline_y as data, how would I add a second 'data set'?

Comment: Never mind, found it: p <- p + stat_function(fun = spl_fun, arg = list(deriv = 2))